# Can't get a Javascript to call a wcf webservice on localhost or on a crm 2013 server

Tags: javascript, wcf, dynamics-crm-2013

Good afternoon. I don't mean to bump the thread, but it's over a month later and I can't seem to get a post OR get request to work. I have looked at (and tried to incorporate) so many pre-written solutions but each and every time some issue seems to come up that I can't resolve. Any help would be seriously appreciated. Thank you tremendously.

an Edit to my problem: I've been trying to create a default WCF service with a simple "Hello message" that accepts POST data per Filburt's suggestion, and I can't get ANYTHING to work at all. Any help would be appreciated. I'm trying to write a test web service for CRM 2013 that will fire from an iframe on a form and call an AJAX enabled WCF webservice sitting on the same crm server. The message will need to send a POST (not get) message to the service. The service seems to be returning a "400" error: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/PasswordResetter/Resetter.svc. Invalid HTTP status code 400". I've tried browsing through 30 or so "Tutorials" and explanations from here, the web, the msdn, and I have no idea what I seem to be doing wrong or why it's not working. I couldn't get it to work from the iframe, nor from a custom html page where the service and html page I created were both on localhost.

Lastly, if this question is somehow "improperly formed" for this site, please point out to me how/why so I may modify it appropriately. Thank you in advance for all of your help.

Below is my Interface:

```
namespace PasswordResetter
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IResetter" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IResetter
    {
        [OperationContract()]
        string test(string a, string b);
    }
}
```

Below is the method:

```
public class Resetter : IResetter
{
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", //was POST
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, //This means that our JSOn will map directly to our parameters with no additional processing??
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "/Test")]
    public string test(string a, string b)
    {
        //return "Success!: " + a + " " + b;
        string myJsonString = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize("Hello World! A: " + a + " b: " + b);
        return myJsonString;
    }
}
```

Here's the Javascript I'm trying to get working:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#iframesubmit').click(function () {
        //var obj = { username: $("#txtuser").val(), name: $("#txtname").val() };
        var obj = '[{ username: $("#password_old").val(), name: $("#password_new").val() }]';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", //was POST
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "http://localhost/PasswordResetter/Resetter.svc",
            //data: "",
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            //data: "{ 'a': '" + $("#password_old").val() + "', 'b': '" + $("#password_new").val() + "'}",//JSON.stringify(obj),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Successfully register");
                document.getElementById("results").value = "Response: " + data; //service.responseText;
                $("#iframesubmit").click();
            },error: function (xhr)
            {
                window.alert('error: ' + xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And finally my web.config:

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>

        <bindings>
          <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="CRMPoint.CRM.Services.PasswordResetter.customBinding0">
          <!--  <binaryMessageEncoding /> -->
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="PasswordResetter">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/PasswordResetter/Resetter.svc" behaviorConfiguration="PasswordResetter.Service1AspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP"
          contract="PasswordResetter.IResetter" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
      <service name="Test">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/PasswordResetter/Resetter.svc" binding="customBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="CRMPoint.CRM.Services.PasswordResetter.customBinding0"
          contract="PasswordResetter" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
      <service name="PasswordResetter.Service1">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/PasswordResetter/Resetter.svc" behaviorConfiguration="PasswordResetter.Service1AspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="PasswordResetter.Service1" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="PasswordResetter.Service1AspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webScriptEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="test" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webScriptEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
    </configuration>`

Comment: Did you already check your IFRAMEs Security option "Restrict cross frame scripting where supported"? Also try using different browsers than IE to see if your request is blocked by IE settings.

Comment: I have not, thank you for the suggestion. I want to enable cors and cross-domain scripting and all that though. And yes I've used IE, FF and Chrome so far and none of them seem to be working. I couldn't get it to work from the iframe, nor from a custom html page where the service and html page I created were both on localhost.

Comment: Hmm ... but surely you are not calling your CRM with http://localhost, right? You should be calling your webservice with the machine name - unless you are doing all this on your crm machine where localhost is indeed identical for all parties involved.

Comment: Both, actually. I've been testing on localhost (my personal laptop) but even when it's deployed live, we host our own crm environments so it's all still in the same domain. I really don't understand the difference, tbh. I have very little experience with web-based technologies.

Comment: I think your best shot will be to place a simple "Hello world!" static html page and see if you can get it displayed in your IFRAME and move onward from there. You'll need some experience in web technologies to troubleshoot this like inspecting requests and responses being sent and received.

Comment: So I can't imagine there's much difference between your suggestion and what I'm already trying to do, right? Could you maybe point me to a real-world, working example? It's going to be a few weeks before I have the free time to delve deep into learning more and in the meantime I've still got to get this working. :)

Comment: Good afternoon. Thank you for all of your advice, Filburt. Can you possibly point me to a good, working example or tutorial by chance of how to use an Ajax script to POST to an ajax enabled WCF service? It seems like all the examples on the first 5 pages of a google search didn't work for me for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

there are some issues in the code...

1. Firstly the method decoration with `WebInvoke` is usually done in the
   interface not in main class
2. Second is the method name `(test)` and the `UriTemplate="/Test"` should be 
   same. It should be like as follows
3. `UriTemplate="/Test"`
    `public string Test(string a, string b)
   {
       string myJsonString = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize("Hello World! A: " + a + " b: " + b);
       return myJsonString;
   }`
4. There is an issue where you do an ajax call to this method
   Replace the following line

> url: "http://localhost/PasswordResetter/Resetter.svc"
>   with
>   url: "http://localhost/PasswordResetter/Resetter.svc/Test"
>   
>   Hope this will help....